# Is it possible to exclude full match with Regular expression?

Tags: regex

I want to write regular expression that would return the string between `Start_MATCHED_End` where `MATCHED` anything but an empty string. However, I don't want to return full match.

Here are some invalid string

```
Start__End
Start_ _End
Start_     _End
off
```

Here are some valid string

```
Start_test_End                      << returns test
Start_123_starts_with_number_End    << returns 123_starts_with_number
Start_end_with_number_123_End       << returns end_with_number_123
Start_contains_a_number_End         << returns contains_a_number
Start_123_End                       << returns 123
```

I write the following regular expression `Start_(.*\S.*)_End`. As you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/DTk3QX/1) it returns two matches per test string
  1. Full Match 
  2. Group 1

How can I exclude the full match from returning?

Comment: You could use the group 1 value. What is the programming language/tool?

Comment: C#, I understand I can loop over the found groups. but hoping I can modify my Regex to exclude full match

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?<=^Start_)\S+(?=_End$)` https://regex101.com/r/Az5SwP/1

Comment: Actually, you don't need to loop over anything. Just `match.Groups[1]` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use positive lookarounds if you want the match only and match 1+ non whitespace chars without the `.*` on the left and the right

```
(?<=^Start_)[^\S\r\n]*\S.*(?=_End\r?$)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5eStart_%29%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*%5cS.*%28%3f%3d_End%5cr%3f%24%29&i=Start_test_End%0d%0aStart_123_starts_with_number_End%0d%0aStart_end_with_number_123_End%0d%0aStart_contains_a_number_End%0d%0aStart_123_End%0d%0aStart_something+with+space_End%0d%0aStart__End%0d%0aStart_++++++_End&o=m)

Comment: This is almost perfect! the case `Start_something with space_End` fails but should be allowed whereas `Start_ _End` or `Start_     _End` is not allowed. the found value cannot be an empty string or white spaces.

Comment: @The forth bird, I hate you for taking away all the regex questions . I have stopped taking a look at them, knowing you would have already reached there

Comment: @John I have added an update to match at least a single non whitespace char to prevent an empty string or spaces only.

Comment: @dumbPy I am sorry you feel that way. I think the answers on regex questions can be very fast and I am certainly not the only one posting answers. But you can always post an answer if you have a good solution that is not yet posted right?

Comment: @The forth bird, Naah man, your answers are always on point. I am just having a banter, no offence meant.